# python bytes b'....\x0009' and b'...\xa1q,)6\x01'

Tags: python, arrays, byte

I'm reading some code and I've run into bytes with the output

```
 b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0009'
 b'\x00\x00\x00...\x9dg\xac\xdf\xa1q,)6\x01'
```

why is \x0009  and \1q,)6 valid?

I don't understand why it's not something like \x00\x09 and how the comma + left parenthesis can appear in byte object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\xAB` notation is used to represent bytes that have no visual representation in ascii. However, when a character does have a representation, it is printed as such.
In your situation, the null byte (`\x00`) does not correspond to an ascii character, while the comma and left parenthesis do. They are actually `\x2c` and `\x28`.
You can test it yourself:

```
b'\x2c\x28' == b',('
True
```

You can find all ascii values [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: cool thanks is the concept applicable to \x0009? where \x00 is a null byte but 09 are the ascii char 0 and 9? what also seems out of the ordinary pattern is \x9dg where 9d is 157 in decimal

Comment: yep, it is applicable for `\x0009`. about that `\x9d`, it seems it is the yen sign in ascii, yet most terminal applications cannot print it. you can test it for yourself using `echo -e '\x9d'`. whether it is out of the ordinary depends on the context